# Is there a way to change the Default user for MySQL event scheduler

Tags: mysql

Context:
I automated an archiving event to only run on weekends by creating an event and defined the user as archive@user (which has permissions to archive processes). When I run the event, the deletes & inserts are done with 'event_scheduler@user'

Question:
I can see from MySQL documentation, that the permissions are taken from the definer user. Does it mean the events always runs with event_scheduler user? Is there any way to change the user on which any specific event runs?
And is there a way to change event_scheduler default user globally for all events?

I tried using a definer clause while creating the event. But that didn't change the user on which the updates are being made

Comment: Perhaps you can make a parallel table and do a trigger event to log the db_user value when this event happens?  Make a stored procedure for the event and put both scripts in there, so it creates the event log via the scheduler then also logs the actual user that triggered it?

Actually .. are you making an event that is not on a timer?  Why not just make a stored procedure instead of an event that isn't actually scheduled but manually ran?

Comment: So Event Scheduler is for making things happen without user interaction.  It could be a one time event, or something that happens every 5 minutes, however you set it up.  But if you have something that is user triggered, why not make the thing a stored procedure with the insert statement so you can just use the CALL command to trigger it, because Events can be set by time to automate .. so it makes little sense to use that for this.

Comment: The event is configured to auto-triggers the archiving stored procedure using the WEEKDAY() function. The event triggers every 30 mins and checks if its weekend. If that passes it run the Archiving stored Procedure.

Comment: I suppose the main reason you are using event is to make it only useable during the weekend?  I suspect you could put some logic into the procedure to detect which day and not run if it was executed on a day other than saturday or sunday.

Comment: I see .. it is automated to run .. so it will log its self as the thing that did it.  So the only other way is build a log system yourself to log this data and just tie it into your existing procedure so it does both logs, one showing the event fired, and another logging the data into a table so you know that information.  But I'm not sure how you would get the variable of who was using the system at the time the event fires, as there could be more than one user logged in so it wouldn't know whom to associate that log.

Comment: Another idea is and without a front end would be tricky, but maybe have a log in table that logs who is in the system and an event clears them out of that table after X amount of time (due to timeout you set).  But this way, you will know who is in the system when the event fires, then you can just log that table data to a another log to pair with the event one.